# Git: Any way to ignore files that have gotten version number changed only

Tags: git, versioning

I'm trying to look at some changes done in a new version of a software named IP.Board. However, when I run a git show between their version 3.4.2 and 3.4.3 in my local repo there is a lot of files that have just gotten their version number updated.

Like this:

```
- * IP.Board v3.4.2
+ * IP.Board v3.4.3
```

Any simple way I can ignore the files where this is the only change made? I guess their version builder automatically updates the version number in all included files.

Comment: There are no sequential version numbers in Git. A better way would be to just get rid of version numbers inside of files.

Comment: This is just one of the reasons that built files should not be included in the repository.

Comment: I don't really have a choice here @WilliamPursell since they are not built by me :/

Comment: If you want to ignore a certain class of *changes* to files, you're probably out of luck, unless you can run some script to undo the changes. If you want to ignore certain files altogether, use `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @KeithThompson. Ignoring the files with .gitignore is not gonna help. I want to have these files in the repo and be updated as new versions come along. 

What I want to be able to do is to easily get a quick overview of changes done between versions sometimes. However it's very time consuming to skip 80% (it feels like) of files that have only had their version number updated when looking for actual changes.

Comment: @user1015149: William Pursell's answer suggests a solution using `.git/config` to change the behavior of `git diff`. My own thought was to write a script (I'd use Perl myself) that filters the output of `git diff`, then run `git diff ... | the-script` as needed; such a script would be more complex that what the answer suggests, but it makes ignoring those differences more explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not incredibly robust, but maybe good enough.  In `.git/config` put:

```
[diff "remove-rev"]
    textconv=sed '/IP.Board v[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*/d'
```

And then in `.gitattributes` or `.git/info/attributes`, put:

```
* diff=remove-rev
```

Now, whenever `git-diff` is run, the sed script will be applied to the file before gitdiffcore decides which file pairs differ.  You may need to tweek the `sed` command to suit your needs, but this should help.

Comment: Do this in a local (hardlinked) clone and it's unintrusive to boot.

Comment: Hi, this seems to be working quite good, thank you so much! :D

Comment: I didn't mean to submit my last comment so soon, either way: 

I found out that some of the changes also had comment like @version 3.4.2 etc. instead, so I just changed to textconv=sed '/v3.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*/d'

The output seems to tell which files it ignored aswell, which I didnt quite expect, but it's faaar better than having it tell all the version changes like it did before. Thanks again!

For example:
diff --git a/admin/applications/core/extensions/editorSections.php b/admin/applications/core/extensions/editorSections.php
index dfe8530..3e6e9f6 100644
diff --git

Answer (score 0):

No. git tracks the content of the file using hash of the file's content. When the version changes, the content change, and so will the hash.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. I know this is not what you want, but I would suggest living with the problem.

Yes, it sucks. However, trying to solve it (or lessen the headache) at the git level is only ensuring that you will live with the problem for longer. The fact is that this is a consequence of a poor design choice when setting up the builds.

You can ignore the files, but you will first have to remove them from git:

1. Backup the files you're about to remove
2. `git rm <files>`
3. commit
4. Restore the files.
5. Edit .gitignore and add the restored files until git says your working tree is clean.

If that's not workable, the best you could do is use a combination of scripts that function as [commit hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that automate as much of the process of managing these files as possible. It will still be a pain, but less so. Again, I recommend you don't go down this path.

UPDATE: If you're not going to be changing those version numbers yourself, you could also use a [filter](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) ( a script that takes two commands - smudge and clean). When the command is smudge, your script would remove the lines with the version number, similar to what William has noted. When the command is clean, your script would add the lines back in.

Note, the key difference between this and William's approach is that using this, even if you open the file in a normal text editor, you won't see the version lines, because this approach would actually modify the file's content - not git's view of it. Therefore, this may not be what you want - the safest approach is what William has suggested, which is changing the way git sees differences.

Here is [more info on both these approaches](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply carleeto, it's not an option for me to gitignore the files. 

After all I would like to keep the software up to date. What I wish is to be able to review the changes done between versions sometimes. I want to be able to see actual changes when they happen, whenever the files are updated, but seeing those changes is not really making it easy to get to the actual changes done.

Comment: Just updated the answer, though it's probably not what you want.